# value extraction from array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

```
business=[0:{"name":{"en":'prateek'}},1:{"name":{"ar":'rahul'}}]
```

How I can extract the value of en and ar from this type of the repeted object in a array

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Comment: For `const business=[{name:{en:'prateek'}},{name:{ar:'rahul'}}] ` you should be able to access over `business[0].name.en` or `business[1].name.ar`.

Comment: @riorudo i am not able to access

Comment: @Prateek Pareek it seems, that your array looks some how different. It works with my example.

Comment: @PrateekPareek you are not pushing proper value in an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue with your question is that you define `business` as an Array with the use of square brackets, but then proceed to use key value pairs directly within the array (via the usage ":"), which is reserved for objects and not arrays. I'd recommend researching both array and object datatypes, however simply put:

```
let myArray = [1, 2, 3, ...]; 
// only stores values which can be retrieved using the values index i.e. myArray[0]

let myObj = {"key1" : "value1", "key2" : "value2"};
// values are stored against keys, and can be accessed via the key i.e. myObj.key1
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you've confused how objects and arrays should work. My guess is that you'd be better off with this structure:

```
let businesses = []; 
businesses.push({enName: 'prateek', arName: 'rahul'});
console.log(businesses[0], businesses[0].enName, businesses[0].arName);
```

This way you're using an array to hold a collection of businesses and which are represented by objects. These objects in turn have attributes for enName and arName.

I think this would be a much clearer way of structuring your issue.